# Getting html to display in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

- I have tried phone:Webbrowser which does not automatically size to the required amount.
- I have tried many textbox and richttextbox property extension libraries, I cannot get any to work.

**I want to know how people get html into textboxes or richtextboxes in windows phone 8.**

Argh, I have spent 2 evenings on this now! doh!

**Context:**

I am calling an API that is returning html (why oh god why)... I want to bind the returned html to a `textbox` or `richtextbox` or if I haveeee to, a `phone:webbrowser`.

Textbox and richtextbox do not support html.

`phone:webbrowser` does not adjust its height according to what's inside the document. You can supposedly do it by enabling javascript and calling `window.external.Notify()` but I couldn't get it to work quite right...

Moving on from the above problem, even if I did get the `phone:webbrowser` to work, if for test purposes I make the width 500 and height 500, I can see my html string as plain text rather than the webcontrol correctly parsing html... doh!

Comment: Could you explain some more? What do you mean by 'not automatically size to the required amount'? Do you want to render the html or be able to edit it?

Comment: edited man, hope that helps you answer

Comment: I got it to work, I had to delete the Doctype part of my html. ffs, this is the crappest tool set ever lol! why can't they give us a nice html parser for richtext ay.!

Comment: Well you should post it as an answer below just in case someone runs into this :) I never had any 'major' issues with rendering html :)

Also, if you need to do some extensive html work, get HTML Agility Pack (available on Nuget)

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, do you know a toolset that has such a parser?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way.

your xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,50,0,0" Name="webBrowser1"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="500" Width="430" />
</Grid>
```

in your code:

```
public MainPage()
{    
InitializeComponent();

webBrowser1.Loaded += WebBrowser_OnLoaded;
}

private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("readme.htm", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Hope it helps